# The birth rate among/for women?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

" The birth rate for women in their 20s in 1993 declined rapidly".
In this example, should I use "among" instead of "for"? Which is more natural?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both prepositions are correct.  Probably,  as you can  see from [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=birth%20rate%20for%20women%2Cbirth%20rate%20among%20women&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), *for* is more commonly used.

From: [Preterm Birth: Causes, Consequences, and Prevention](https://books.google.it/books?id=Wh5KAt_X3RkC&pg=PA44&dq=%22birth%20rate%20for%20women%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwju2PiujtrcAhVLsqQKHWPhDA0Q6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=%22birth%20rate%20for%20women%22&f=false):

> In 2003, women ages 30 to 34 experienced the highest ***birth rate for women*** in this age group since the mid- 1970s and women ages 40 to 44 had the highest birth rate for women in this age group since the late 1960s

From [Avery's Diseases of the Newborn](https://books.google.it/books?id=UxELwb0iOt0C&pg=PA1&dq=%22birth%20rate%20among%20women%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig25XbjtrcAhUEzaQKHU1kDJQQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%22birth%20rate%20among%20women%22&f=false):

> ***The birth rate among women*** 20 to 24 years old decreased by 2%, whereas that in women 25 to 44 years old continued to increase